# ReactCSSTransitionsGroup With Dynamic Styles Doesn't Execute Enter Animation Properly On Anything Other Than The First Item

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Trying to build a nifty animation for launching dialogs but running into a snag with ReactCSSTransitionsGroup. The goal is to ensure that the dialog looks like its zooming out of the button that launched it.  Below is a sample that shows the working demo.

The math looks good, the css looks good, the component looks good.  The unexpected behavior exhibited is the following

1. Click on the first button (either one).  Works perfectly.
2. Click on the second button, the enter animation does not play.
3. Doesn't matter how many buttons you add, only the first works as expected.  All additional buttons won't show the enter animation properly.
4. The leave animation works for all buttons.

Trying to figure out if there's something wrong with the code, unintended usage of ReactCSSTransitionsGroup or a bug with it.

[Fiddle is here](https://jsfiddle.net/bqbj2z24/20/)

Thanks!

```js
let ReactCSSTransitionGroup = React.addons.CSSTransitionGroup;
let StyleSheet = aphrodite.StyleSheet;
let css = aphrodite.css


const Button = (props) => {
    return <div className="button" onClick={(e) => props.onClick(e)}>Click me</div>;
}



let emptyStyleSheet = StyleSheet.create({
 enter: {},
    enterActive: {},
    leave: {},
    leaveActive: {}
});


class UnicornDialog extends React.Component {

 constructor(props) {
     super(props);
  this.state = {sheet: emptyStyleSheet};
    }

 componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps, nextContext){
        if (!nextProps.show) {
            return;
        }

        let viewportRect = document.body.getBoundingClientRect();
        let sourceRect = nextProps.startRect;
        
        let viewportCenterX = viewportRect.left + (viewportRect.width / 2);
        let viewportCenterY = viewportRect.top + (viewportRect.height / 2);

        let sourceCenterX = sourceRect.left + (sourceRect.width / 2);
        let sourceCenterY = sourceRect.top + (sourceRect.height / 2);

        let dx = sourceCenterX - viewportCenterX;
        let dy = sourceCenterY - viewportCenterY;
        
        let sheet = StyleSheet.create({
            enter: { 
             opacity: 0, 
                transform: `translate(${dx}px, ${dy}px) scale(0.01)` 
            },
            enterActive: { 
             opacity: 1, 
                transform: "translate(0, 0) scale(1)", transition: "transform 750ms cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.2, 1), opacity 750ms cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.2, 1)" 
            },
            leave: {
             opacity: 1, 
                transform: "translate(0, 0) scale(1)"
            },
            leaveActive: { 
             opacity: 0, 
                transform: `translate(${dx}px, ${dy}px) scale(0.01)`, 
                transition: "transform 750ms cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.2, 1), opacity 750ms cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.2, 1)" 
            }
        })

        this.setState(sheet);
    }

    render() {
        let child = <div key={"dialog"}
            className="dialog"
            onClick={this.props.onClick}>click anywhere to dismiss</div>;

  if (!this.props.show) {
            child = null;
        }

        return <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
   transitionName={{
              enter: css(this.state.enter),
                enterActive: css(this.state.enterActive),
                leave: css(this.state.leave),
                leaveActive: css(this.state.leaveActive)
            }}
            transitionEnterTimeout={750}
            transitionLeaveTimeout={750}>
            {child}
        </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
    }
}





class Parent extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { startRect: null, show: false };
    }

    showDialog(e) {
        let startRect = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
        let show = true;
        this.setState({ startRect, show });
    }

    hideDialog() {
        this.setState({ startRect: null, show: false });
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Button onClick={this.showDialog.bind(this)} />
                <Button onClick={this.showDialog.bind(this)} />
                <UnicornDialog {...this.state} onClick={this.hideDialog.bind(this)} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}




ReactDOM.render(< Parent />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

```css
body {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.button {
    position: absolute;
    height: 32px;
    line-height: 32px;
    width: 128px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid rgba(64, 64, 64, 0.1);
    background-color: #e74c3c;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.button:first-child {
    top: 64px;
    left: 64px;
}

.button:nth-child(2) {
    top: 264px;
    left: 264px;
}

.dialog {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    z-index: 100;
    background-color: #34495e;
    color: #ecf0f1;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/react@15.4.0/dist/react-with-addons.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/aphrodite@1.1.0/dist/aphrodite.umd.js"></script>

<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

Comment: I think the issue is the lack of keys for each child of the reactcsstransitiongroup. Each child the that gets rendered needs its own key.

Comment: the div element has a key.  I tried replacing the null element with an empty div with a key and it still behaves the same.

Answer (score 0):

Figured this one out - its a bug in the styles.  ReactCSSTransitionGroup will apply both enter and enterActive.  When applying those, effectively the `enter` style is applied but not the active.